# Is there any way make "nopagebreak" work before "longtable"?

Tags: longtable

I've found `\nopagebreak` not working before `longtable` whereas it works before `tabular`.

Is there a solution to make it work?

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{18cm}
    Title above longtable\nopagebreak[4]

\begin{longtable}[l]{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
        aa&bb\\
    \hline
        aa&bb\\
    \hline

\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please add some background informtion on why you want the line of text to stay at the same page as the longtable? Is this line of text a caption for the longtable?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround, put all content in a `minipage`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{longtable}

\begin{document}
    \vspace*{18cm}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}
    Title above longtable

\begin{longtable}[l]{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|}
    \hline
        aa&bb\\
    \hline
        aa&bb\\
    \hline

\end{longtable}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I misunderstood.

With `\vspace*{17.7cm}` it perfectly breaks. I guess `\vspace*{18cm}` is simply not compatible with the margins.

Comment: What's the point of using `longtable` in this case? The whole point is it allows page breaks. If you don't need them, you can just use `tabular` instead.